# What does "range("F:F")" mean in an Excel macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm debugging a macro and have very little experience with them, what does the f:f mean? I understand the first range and I'm guessing the f:f means the currently selected range but that's just a guess.

```
       ws.Range("A1:M65536").ClearContents
       ws.Range("F:F").FormatConditions.Delete
```

Could someone clarify for me please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means the range that is the entire `F` column. `F:H` is columns `F`, `G` and `H` etc.

Comment: so in this particular example would `ws.Range("A1:M65536").ClearContents` be better replaced by  `ws.Range("A:M").ClearContents` assuming it is the entire columns that needed to be deleted that is

Comment: I'm not an expert but using `A:M` seems more clean compared to `A1:M65536`. Even though the end row probably is larger than the size of the worksheet it seems arbitrary.

Comment: +1 Martin :) @Jacxel: Yes it is much better to use `ws.Range("A:M").ClearContents`. Also this will work in all versions of Excel. In Excel 2007 onwards the original code will not clear the contents from row 65537 onwards :)

Answer (score 6):

`F:F` means the entire `F` column.